# Magento and Campaign monitor integration

Tags: magento

Is there a simple way to integrate campaign monitor into Magento (CE).

Specifically I want customers to be signed upto a "customer" mailing list once they have made a successfull purchase.

I've tried a couple of extensions but this functionality is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a old post.
But there is a new Magento Campaign Monitor extension that is compatible with the newer Magento Versions.
You can find it overhere.
https://github.com/weprovide/Magento_Campaign_Monitor